# Is implementing the UITableViewDataSource protocol required for table functionality

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

Ive created a class with the declaration

> class LessonDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
>   @IBOutlet var detailsTable: UITableView!

I can populate the contents in my table and provide operations by implementing the 
proper tableView functions.

But I did not implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol where all these functions are defined. Can someone please explain to me what key concept I'm missing that makes this possible?  How does iOS know to call these methods of this class doesn't implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Answer (score 0):

you must need to implement required method of UITableview dataSource and delegate method.

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0):

Your class definitely should implement necessary methods from this protocol. This is enough to allow table view work because, even if you not declare that your class implements this protocol, your class can perform table view delegate methods. In your case, table view calls your class in order to get some data and does not check if it `conformsToProtocol`, just sends a message like `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: thanks so much Mike! Just so I clearly understand, the view is blindly looking for methods on the controller to call with or without it implementing the protocol. I definitely see how its cleaner and more readable to have the protocol implemented but at which point would functionality "not work" without having this protocol defined on the class? Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

OK I am going to try to explain how to wire up your tableView but i am going to use Swift

Now you have this:

```
class LessonDetailsViewController: UIViewController { @IBOutlet var detailsTable: UITableView! }
```

You have to make this view controller to comfort to two necessary protocols for the tableView to work

So add UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

So now the code look like this

```
   class LessonDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { @IBOutlet var detailsTable: UITableView! }
```

If you make the changes correctly you are getting an error {LessonDetailsViewController does not comfort ........ }. This is because UITableViewDataSource has two required function you have to implement. There are many in both protocols but they are optional.

The first function is witch describe what each will look like.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{}
```

The second one is  witch tells the tableView how many rows to show.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{}
```

And finally you have to wire up the tableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        detailsTable.delegate = self
        detailsTable.dataSource = self
    }
```

A protocol generally defines some function but is not implementing them. So in source code tableView is using this functions but you have to implement them first. By adding UITableViewDataSource next to UIViewController you basically telling the system that LessonDetailsViewController is going to implement these functions that the tableView need